# Load webpage on an overlay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a page overlay with a click of a button but I could not find a way to load an http page such as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) on this overlay. I am looking to load a mini webpage inside an overlay. Is there a way to achieve this?
I know about iframe and how its used to load external links. How do I use iframe to this overlay?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('#fade-wrapper').fadeIn();
  });
  
  $('#fade-wrapper').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#fade-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fade-wrapper"></div>
<input class="button" type="button" value="Overlay Button" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

The HTML Inline Frame element `<iframe>` allows you to next an external website within the frame. Simply placing it inside your `fade-wrapper` element will achieve what you're trying to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('#fade-wrapper').fadeIn();
  });
  
  $('#fade-wrapper').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
  
  $('#fade-wrapper-close').click(function() {
    $('#fade-wrapper').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#fade-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#fade-wrapper-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fade-wrapper">
  <button id="fade-wrapper-close">Close</button>
  <iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://google.com"></iframe>
</div>
<input class="button" type="button" value="Overlay Button" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot! I am however getting an error that google has refused to connect. Even though I am using local host to connect it.

Comment: Only certain websites can be framed. The reason for can't load google.com is that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. This option prevents the browser from displaying iFrames that are not hosted on the same domain as the parent page.

Comment: Oh no that is sad. I might have to find a way to bypass this.

Comment: Sorry I am still new to this. Is there a way to create a button inside the overlay to close the overlay?

Comment: I've added a close button to my example 

Answer (score 0):

If you need just insert a remote page inside your page content, you can use an `iframe`

```
<div id="fade-wrapper">
   <iframe src="myURL" style="width=100vw; height=100vh" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

More info about iframe: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe